# What is better, use the join spark method or get a dataset already joined by sql?

Tags: java, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have to decide which of the following is the best option to do a SQL join:

- Getting into Datasets each table rows and then use the `Dataset.join(Dataset)` spark method.
- Getting joined tables by passing the join query as `dbtable` option to a `DataframeReader`.

I have the queries for two tables, and in some cases their resultset size may differ a lot. I'm looking for take advantage of spark, but without overloading it.

Given the two following queries:

```
query1 = SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SOME_FILEDS) ID, MORE_FIELDS FROM TABLE1 WHERE CONDITIONS;
query2 = SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by FIELD) id, SOME_FIELDS FROM TABLE2 WHERE CONDITIONS;
```

**First option**

I get the rows into the Datasets:

```
Dataset<Row> table1 = getDataset(query1);
Dataset<Row> table2 = getDataset(query2);
```

And finally do the join:

```
Dataset<Row> joined = table1.join(table2);
```

**Second option**

Build a join query

```
joinQuery = query1 join query2
```

I get the rows into a Dataset:

```
Dataset<Row> joined = getDataset(joinQuery);
```

Comment: The data is in some external database?

Comment: Yes, the data is in an external database (AWS)